# Change Date Format In Python

Tags: python

I need to convert date string "Dec 17 00:00:06" to string "2014-12-17 00:00:06" in python. I looked at the datetime.strptime but still can't find a way for this.
eg:

> Dec 17 00:00:06 to 2014-12-17 00:00:06

Comment: datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 17 2014", '%b %d %Y').strftime('%Y-/%m-/%d')

this will handle the dilemma regarding your date.

Comment: Year is missing in your input string?

Comment: yes there is no year. so is there any way to convert without year.?

Comment: In that case please tell us how to determine the year for a date string that doesn't have one.

Comment: what could be the pattern of "2014-12-17 00:00:15.85 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime` module.

For e.g.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> do = datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 17 2014 00:00:06", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
>>> do.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2014-12-17 00:00:06'
```

We can replace year value to `2014` like following:

```
>>> do = datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 17 00:00:06", "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
>>> do.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'1900-12-17 00:00:06'
>>> do1 = do.replace(year=2014)
>>> do1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2014-12-17 00:00:06'
```

If we want only `time` value then we can try like-

```
>>> do = datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 17 00:00:06", "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
>>> do.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'00:00:06'
```

**Updated:** update datetime string from file with its time string.

Algo:

1. Get content from the input text file.
2. Used `re` module i.e regular expression to get all pattern from content.
3. Use `set` method to remove duplicate values.
4. Convert datetime string to time string and update content.
5. Write new content into same file or other file.

code is:-

```
import datetime
import re
p = "/home/vivek/Desktop/input.txt"
with open(p, "rb") as fp:
    content = fp.read()

date_values = set(re.findall("\[([^]]+)\]", content))
for i in date_values:
    do = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
    content = content.replace("[%s]"%i, "%s"%(do.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) )

p = "/home/vivek/Desktop/output.txt"
with open(p, "wb") as fp:
    fp.write(content)
```

Comment: there is no year over there.

Comment: is there any possibility to remove all year and month from there. i need o/p as : Dec 17 00:00:06 to 00:00:06

Comment: @SnehasishMohanta: Update according to your request, Can you check?

Comment: ok, every line in the text file contains such date formats `Dec 17 00:00:06`. right? So we have to create new file with time format`00:00:06`. right?

Comment: ok, `Dec 17 00:00:05` this format is always inside square bracket  `[]`. right?

Comment: yes i got. but i am having a text file name " a.txt" which contain a same format like below:
[Dec 17 00:00:00]  stives,  0,
[Dec 17 00:00:04]  westjackets,  0,
[Dec 17 00:00:05]  combo,  10,
[Dec 17 00:00:05]  combo,  10,
[Dec 17 00:00:05]  comb,  10,
[Dec 17 00:00:06]  combo,  10,
[Dec 17 00:00:06]  combo,  10,
[Dec 17 00:00:06]  combo,  10,
from this i need :
00:00:00 ,  stives,  0,
00:00:04 ,  westjackets,  0,
00:00:05 ,  combo,  10,
00:00:05 ,  combo,  10,
00:00:05 ,  comb,  10,
00:00:06 ,  combo,  10,
00:00:06 , combo,  10,
00:00:06 ,  combo,  10,
is it possible

Comment: ok, We have to replace ` [Dec 17 00:00:05]` with  `[00:00:05]` in same file or need to write new file with these chnages?

Comment: yes this format always in square bracket.but i need to remove it

Comment: it's ok if it can be replace then good. other wise we can make a new file

Comment: square bracket i dont want

Comment: @SnehasishMohanta: Can you check again, I updated my solution?

Comment: @SnehasishMohanta: update update with file opretion work for you or get any more exception in code? if any mail me vivekbsable@gmail.com

Comment: what could be the pattern of " 2014-12-17 00:00:15.85 "

Comment: means you want to give space " " at start and end of date string ?

Comment: no. i just want to know the pattern of 2014-12-17 00:00:15.85

Comment: by using `strftime` method of `datetime` module qw can generate any type of datetime format e.g do1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") and also check email.

Answer (score 0):

Using datetime module will help you out.

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Firstly convert your date string to a datetime object by writing the line below.

```
date_obj = datetime.strptime("Dec 17 2014 00:00:06", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Then convert that date object to a string.

```
date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

You can change the parameters of the above strftime() function, and get different formats as per your requirments. Please follow [python datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Here is the link to the options for the parameters which can be passed in the strftime() function [parameter options](http://strftime.org/)

Go and play around as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse('Dec 17 00:00:06').isoformat()
>>> '2015-12-17T00:00:06'
```